# 404 error derivative service Autodesk Forge (Viewer not showing)

Tags: autodesk-forge

I have had an online dashboard including a the Forge Viewer and some weeks ago it just stopped working, without me changing any of the code. Now I can log into my docs and get all the folders and files but when trying to load the viewer this error appears:

GET https://developer.api.autodesk.com/derivativeservice/v2/manifest/...?domain=... 404 (Not Found)

Any idea?

Comment: Can you tell me your process, Are you storing your files in your own Bucket? or in a BIM 360 Docs Hub?

Comment: I use the BIM 360 Docs Hub.

I am using the code found in this project:

https://bim360reports.autodesk.io/